# Can drawing a duck define a person's hemispheric dominance?

Tags: personality, test, lateralization, brain

When I was on 7<sup>th</sup> grade, our math teacher asked every one of us to draw a duck. In the class of 34 students, a large portion of the students drew a left-facing duck.

[image: doodle of the duck]

The teacher said that it’s a simple test to figure out if a person is either right or left-brain dominant. So the people who drew a duck facing to left is a right-brainer, and *vice versa*. Apparently this Duck-test was quite popular in middle school.

Some even say, people who often draw a duck who faces left side is a left brain (instead of right). Although some says it's just muscle memory/ tendency.

My question is- is this mini test legit? 
Can you get a glimpse of someone's brain dominance by drawing a duck?

Answer (score 3):

What is the dominant hemisphere in the first place? I found the following definition (source: [Medical Dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/dominant+hemisphere)):

> [The] dominant hemisphere [is] [t]he left half of the brain in almost all right-handed people and 85% of left-handed people. This is the hemisphere concerned with **language** and **logical thought** and containing the **motor areas for voluntary use of the right side of the body**. In 15% of left-handed people, the right hemisphere is dominant and subserves speech.

Now, your ducks facing left or right hardly seem to reflect either language, logic, motor lateralization or handedness. Instead, often [questionnaires](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~bemorton/Hemisphericity/PolarityQ.html) or [inventories](http://personality-testing.info/tests/OHBDS/) are used, for example to tease out whether a person is logical, rational and verbal (left-sided); or emotional, manipulative/spatial and creative (right-sided). However, the meaning, relevance, and possible use of hemispheric dominance is [debated](http://personality-testing.info/tests/OHBDS/).

Note that brain lateralization is certainly true for a number of functions, including speech and motor control, but the more dramatic examples of brain lateralization should be interpreted with caution, and I quote from [Corballis (1980)](http://www.academia.edu/download/3679701/American_Psychologist.pdf):

> Since ancient times, right and left have been associated with different fundamental classifications, including male and female, good and evil, day
>   and night, straight and crooked. [...] Interpretations of cerebral asymmetry that emphasize a **fundamental duality in cognitive processing** between the two sides of the brain, or that locate **consciousness in the left side only**, are probably modern manifestations of the age-old **mythology** of left and right.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Corballis, *American Psychologist* (1980); **35**(3): 284-95](http://www.academia.edu/download/3679701/American_Psychologist.pdf)</sub>